# Question about velocity vectors

Tags: vector-analysis, vectors

Let $ \vec x(t)$ be a path of class $C^1$ that does not pass through the origin 
in $R^3$. If $\vec x(t_0)$ is the point on the image of $\vec x$ closest to the origin and $\vec x'(t_0) \ne 0$, show that the position vector $\vec x(t_0)$ is orthogonal to the velocity vector $\vec x'(t_0)$.

My goal is:$$ \vec x(t_0)\cdot \vec x'(t_0)=0$$

Since $\vec x(t_0)$ is the closest point to the origin we must have:$$2x(t_0)x'(t_0)+2y(t_0)y'(t_0)+2z(t_0)z'(t_0)=0$$
where $x,y,z$ are the vector components of $\vec x$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: i made a mistake writing derivatives...now all it's right

Comment: No, it isn't right. You still havent posted your work on the question.

Answer (score 1):

The square from the distance from the origin is given by
$$d(t)^2=\vec x(t)\cdot \vec x(t).$$
Since the path is $C^1$, the minimum will be attained when
$$\frac{d}{dt}(d^2)(t_0)=0 \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}(\vec x\cdot \vec x)(t_0)=0 \Rightarrow2\vec x(t_0)\cdot \vec x'(t_0)=0.$$
So, the velocity is orthogonal to the position at $t_0$.